# /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase: 590: cannot open /home/mathieu/dummy/.git/rebase-merge/rewritten: No such file

Tags: git

I tried a rebase of my local branch (call it 'local') into master. Here is what I did:

```
$ git checkout local
$ git rebase -s ours master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
...
Already applied: 0017 smore more work
/usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase: 590: cannot open /home/mathieu/dummy/.git/rebase-merge/rewritten: No such file
All done.
```

I can find some references to my local branch from the comment, but I do not know how to resurect the code. Eg:

```
$ cd .git && grep -lr "smore more work" *
logs/refs/heads/progresscallback
logs/HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the rebase didn't actually succeed fully?

What you probably want to do is look at `git reflog show local`. You should see some previous positions of the `local` branch, hopefully something generally like this:

```
d22ffd5 local@{0}: rebase finished: refs/heads/local onto fd02971501218f3817ceffa970ae9a4813139ae0
9011ecf local@{1}: commit: foo
6134eab local@{2}: commit: bar
```

and assuming `local` is still checked out (check it out if it's not) all you need do is `git reset --hard 9011ecf`, where that's the SHA1 of the commit the branch pointed to just before the rebase. That will, very simply, reset the `local` branch to point back to that commit again, and update your index and work tree along with it.

Comment: Very *very* impressive ! Thanks you saved me quite some time.